# Account suspended for deletions of old 0-voted posts

Tags: discussion

I wanted to do a cleanup in my posts.
I started deleting those that have never been accepted or upvoted in a long time: worthless by definition.
I can only assume that's ok, there's even a **delete** button right underneath the post....
And with all the talk about the *"garbage"* floating around SO, I thought I would earn a badge for that.
Well, my account got SUSPENDED !

One moderator argued that *"...extensive deletions take a lot of effort to repair"*.
I did not understand that statement and asked for clarification.
A second moderator told me to *"...please be in a little less of a rush to remove it"*.
That makes no sense either given that SO already imposes a 5/Day deletion limit...

So I decided to post it here on Meta.
Can I delete it or not ?

Comment: How many posts were you deleting? A couple, dozens, hundreds?

Comment: Either way I have a suggestion for a better title

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm deleting 5/day... I like my headline better....

Comment: Can I ask why you consider answers that haven't been upvoted/accepted "worthless by definition"? You presumably wrote them to be useful for someone/somewhere and not just for votes? Don't forget that readers of your answers may not even be members to cast a vote - it doesn't mean the content is "worthless". Destruction of content is taken seriously hence the 5/day self-deletion rule.

Comment: Hmm, George has been on the war-path again today.  But long distance, your account does not look very suspended.  Are you sure they were not just threa^H^H^H^H^H gentle reminders?

Comment: @JonClements if it was not accepted by the PO or up voted by anyone else, well... it's worthless by definition. Can I have my headline back?

Comment: @HansPassant they put it back after a while, but i still need to find out where the _"line-on-the-sand"_ is.

Comment: @jstreet I'm happy for you to make any point you wish to make (although I'm failing to see what that is right now) - you were suspended for a total of 2 hours, and were advised by a fellow mod about our concerns on content deletion. If you consider them "worthless" - why did you bother wasting your time writing them in the first place? And no - there's no need for such an inflammatory title - it comes off as a rant, and if you want a civilised discussion/community input - such a thing will not be in your favour.

Comment: @JonClements the fact these posts have not been accepted or up voted surpasses whatever opinion i may have.... Inflammatory? Really?

Comment: @jstreet I don't know whether the title was *inflammatory* but it was certainly not helpful for people looking at questions in a search (for instance) and seeing the title you had, which was utterly non-descriptive of what your question is about.

Comment: @JonClements then don't use the word _inflammatory_....

Comment: @jstreet Louis said he doesn't think it's inflamatory. Jon never backed up from that statement.

Comment: If you had just deleted them, I'm not sure I would have thought much was wrong, but you defaced every single post you deleted, which made me wonder what was amiss. In the future, you'll likely get a lot less scrutiny from deleting your posts if you don't deface them first.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I **deleted** it first and THEN erased its contents.

Comment: @jstreet point still stands. If you don't want scrutiny, don't deface them. Why did you deface them, anyway?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I erased its contents AFTER deleting it, so it shouldn't matter. Now, if there's a ruling saying that i can delete but not erase content, then i need to know.

Comment: considering that mods can (and have) brought up answers that were deleted... then yeah, it kinda goes with it that defacing, even deleted posts, isn't a good idea on Stack...

Comment: You deleted an answer that you created less then 24 hours ago on a question that was posted the day before you answered? I can understand if it was an old question and answer but deleting a new answer from a question that does not have an accepted answer? From looking at one question it appears your answer is better then the other answer on the question and you just need to give the person who asked the question a little time to respond to the answer received.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your activity was unusual enough that it triggered a flag within the system. There are a few such checks within the system, both to prevent abuse and things like hijacking.

So a moderator suspended your account and asked you if anything odd was going on. Once you confirmed that all was well, the suspension was lifted.

This is the system working as intended, to protect itself and you.

Comment: And thank heavens that the mod blocked the account after it was already blocked from deleting more, Lord knows what could happen next.  Threats.

Comment: For some reason, I suspect that was not a sincere comment... But the sincere response is: edit vandalism, vulgar answers, trolling questions. We got rather a lot of hijacked accounts recently, and although we've tried to make that a bit less convenient I certainty had time to become familiar with the patterns.

Comment: Ok, so can i continue deleting it ?

Comment: If you're convinced the posts you're deleting aren't beneficial, sure. Put a bit of thought into it - Nicol makes a reasonable point as well, its not always obvious what'll end up being useful. But ultimately, be true to yourself.

Answer (score 10):

> deleting those that have never been accepted or upvoted in a long time

So, you decided that, because nobody upvoted or accepted an answer of yours, it was a posteriori worthless and therefore worthy of deletion.

No, it isn't.

Content is *content*, whether upvoted or not. Zero-vote answers may be valuable to someone who didn't have upvoting privileges, or the person may have thought that they weren't worthy of upvotes. Or maybe, someone would have seen it tomorrow, liked it, and upvoted it.

So just because an answer hasn't been upvoted is not proof that the answer isn't valuable.

The power to delete answers should only be used when it is clearly wrong (ie: someone pointed out an error you made) or something likewise. Not merely content that nobody has visibly appreciated, but content that clearly is causing misinformation by being visible.

Comment: No, it was a **posteriori** worthless, therefore the deletion.....

Comment: If it isn't downvoted it isn't worthless. The assumption comes in equating posts without downvotes as being useless.  Worthless things around here get downvoted, or removed indiscriminately (e.g., comments).

Comment: @jstreet If *nobody* has posted feedback on its quality then its value is *unknown*, it's not known to be worthless (or of negative worth).  If was attracting lots of downvotes, then that would be sending a signal that it was actually evaluated by people, and found to not have positive value.  A post with *no* feedback could be great, terrible, or anything inbetween.  You won't be able to say until people actually evaluate it.

Comment: @Servy *If nobody has posted feedback on its quality then its value is unknown, it's not known to be worthless* - FWIW, every time there's a discussion about a question ban, someone always says that zero score posts **do** count against you. Is it just that a 0 score for questions are bad but not for answers or are people confused about how the system views a post with no votes.?

Comment: @BSMP It counts a *very small* amount against you.  That said that's not at all inconsistent with treating those posts as being of unknown value.